# Q: In self-executing function, Who is assigned the number 10

Tags: javascript

I saw an interview question online:

```js
function b() {
    b = 5
    console.log(b) // 5
}
b()
console.log(b) // 5

var a = 20
var c = (function a() {
    a = 10
    console.log(a) // f a() { a = 10; console.log(a) }
})()
console.log(a) // 20
```

Why does `console.log(a)` print `function a() { a = 10; console.log(a) }` instead of `10`?

Comment: The older I get the less useful I find asking these sort of questions. I'd much rather walk through some code that the candidate is especially proud of and discuss why they have done things in a certain way. If code such as the above were in production, it would be backed up by a comment.

Comment: Because https://tc39.es/ecma262/2020/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation
TLDR in function expression binding to name `a` is immutable.